# Mount a docker volume on an OS X host

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

Is it possible to mount a docker volume running on OS X as a drive on the OS X host? For instance, I have a docker volume defined called `data` which I can mount on any docker container fine. Instead, I would like to mount that volume somehow so I can look at the files directly from my OS X host.

Comment: i'm not sure if osxfs will help but it seems possible  https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/

Comment: I've used it but as it states: `provides a close-to-native user experience for bind mounting macOS file system trees into Docker containers`, I'm looking to take data out of docker volumes into a macOS file system

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly edit the contents of named volumes.  On non-Linux hosts, this is further complicated by the volume content being stored inside a hidden Linux virtual machine.  (On native Linux, you really shouldn't; on other platforms, you actually can't.)

Depending on how you need to access the files, you could `docker run` a temporary container mounting the volume; `docker exec` a shell in a container that already has it mounted; or abandon the existing volume and use a host bind mount instead.  You could adapt Docker's [documentation on backing up named volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-a-container) to do something like

```
docker run -v some-volume:/data -w /data busybox tar cf - . \
  | tar xf -
```

to copy the contents of a named volume on to the host.

Comment: I've been using your `docker run` suggestion to poke around. piping the data out with tar is a great idea, thank you!